# Visual Studio 2017 - Unable to push committed changes to local repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I'm running VS 2017 Enterprise (15.7.3) on Win 10 Enterprise.  I have a git repository on my local hard drive where I've made some changes and now wish to use VS to "commit and push" these changes to our central repository which is located on one of our network file shares.

The error message I get is:

```
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository 
exists.
```

a) This has worked for me for some time up until yesterday.  As far as I know, there's been no updates or other changes to my machine.

b) When I use git from the command line, I am able to push these changes to our central repository and VS Synchronization Window reflects that fact (No more outgoing commits.)

```
 git status before using command line to push:
     On branch master
          Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
          (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
          nothing to commit, working tree clean
 git status after using command line to push:
     On branch master
     Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
     nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

c) Using the VS Installer, I've attempted to uninstall (reboot) /reinstall (reboot) "Git for Windows" to no avail.

Everything I've been able to find so far is geared towards problems using GitHub which is not my situation.

Comment: Did you configure your credentials to github in git command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like a problem in your credentials configuration to github, i advise you to go on terminal and store your credentials using the following commands:

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. That being said, we are not using github -- our central repository is just a file ("Fred.git" for example) on one of our network shares.  Also, push works fine when using command line ("git push")

Comment: Looks like your VS is trying to connect to a remote repository, maybe the github integration on VS have some default configurations

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an "answer" but SO won't let me contribute via comment yet on this issue.  Same issue started for me last Friday afternoon.  I have updated everything to current versions (VS2017 - 15.7.3, all plugins, extensions, and Git for Windows; running on Windows 7).  Command line push to remote works as @DataBeagle indicates and following that the counts and statuses showing in VS2017 are correctly reflecting the push happened.

Credentials are not an issue as we are not using Git Hub, only pushing to remote repo on internal network share.

Comment: Note - there is an active thread on developercommunity.visualstudio.com for this.  Search for "cannot push to remote repository since update from 15.7.2 to 15.7.3".

Answer (score 0):

My VS2017 version is 15.7.4, found a same problem, and finally managed to solve it.
The solution was originally found here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/19752/git-cant-clone-remote-repository.html

Open up the following file location and delete its contents:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git
```

Open **vs2017 installer** (either through the installer .exe file or open vs2017, click the menu *Tools - Get Tools and Features...*), go to "Individual Item" tab, **uncheck** "Git for Windows", click "Modify".
Then, reactivate it by **check**ing "Git for Windows", and click "Modify".

Answer (score 0):

the above issue is resolved for me by changing the credential in my windows setting.
Go to Control Panel --> User Account --> Credential Manager

In Credential Manager, you will see the vscodevscode.github.xxx and edit that with your username and GitHub token and save it and then try to do everything again hope this will resolve it.

For Github Access token:
Go to Github Setting ---> Developer setting ---> Personal Access Token ---> Generate New Token ---> Note (Name something) and tick (repo, admin: org and gist) and click on Generate token.

Now just copy and paste this token with username in vscodevscode.github.xxx.